# Normalizer, stabilizer and orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, group-actions

I know relation between normalizer of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ and the stabilizer of one point $x$ of a set $Ω$ on which the group acts. Given that$$
\gcd([G:\operatorname{Normalizer}(H)], [G:\operatorname{Stab}(x)])=1,
$$
i.e.$$
G=\operatorname{Stab}(x) \operatorname{Normalizer}(H).
$$
Now I put $H:=\operatorname{Stab}(x)$ and I do not have gcd. Can I write similar factorization?

Comment: Well, $H\subseteq N_G(H)$, so $HN_G(H)$ would just be $N_G(H)$.